# C++ libcurl responses only show first line of response

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

EDIT: After running a few more commands, it seems that only lines starting with `*` are being shown. Any way to stop that?

I'm trying to use the [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl.html) library with my C++ program to recieve emails using the IMAP protocol. The issue is that the response from the CURL calls are only returning one line, and cutting off the rest of what is supposed to be returned. I know that the request itself is working because when I turn on verbose mode with `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);`, it has the full result within the output.

For example, when I use `curl_easy_setopt(curl, "FETCH 10000 (FLAGS BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (DATE FROM SUBJECT)])");` the response is:

```
* 10000 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen) BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (DATE FROM SUBJECT)] {140}
```

When I turn on verbose mode, the console includes the full result:

```
< A003 OK [READ-WRITE] INBOX selected. (Success)
> A004 FETCH 10000 (FLAGS BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (DATE FROM SUBJECT)])
< * 10000 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen) BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (DATE FROM SUBJECT)] {140}
< Date: Wed, 1 Apr 2020 01:59:45 -0500
< From: [REMOVED NAME] <[REMOVED EMAIL]>
< Subject: Testing subject here
< 
< )
< A004 OK Success
```

I have tried multiple ways of outputting the data: to stdout, an external file, and in memory (then printed). I feel like the CURL result just isn't returning more than the first line for some reason. Here is the code if it helps (I'm using wxWidgets):

**App.cpp** - Ignore most of this, just calls the functions

```
#include "App.h"
#include "Frame.h"
#include "Config.h"
#include "IMAP.h"


wxIMPLEMENT_APP(App);

bool App::OnInit() {
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_SSL);
    try {
        Config config("settings.conf");
        for(const auto& account : config["accounts"]) {
            const char* url = account["incoming_server"].asCString();
            const char* username = account["username"].asCString();
            const char* password = account["password"].asCString();
            IMAP connection(url, IMAP_DEFAULT_PORT);
            if(connection.auth(username, password) == IMAP_SUCCESS) {
                connection.select("INBOX");
                auto folders = connection.getFolders();
            }
        }
    } catch(std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();
    exit(1);

    Frame *frame = new Frame("MailDuck", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(100, 100));
    frame->Show(true);
    frame->Centre();
    return true;
}
```

**App.cpp**

```
#include "IMAP.h"

IMAP::IMAP(const char *url, int port) {
    this->url = url;
    this->port = port;
}

IMAP_CODE IMAP::auth(const char *username, const char *password) {
    this->username = username;
    this->password = password;
    if(execute().size == -1) return IMAP_FAILED;
    else return IMAP_SUCCESS;
}

std::vector<Folder> IMAP::getFolders() {
    std::vector<Folder> folders;
    memory mem = execute("FETCH 10000 (FLAGS BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (DATE FROM SUBJECT)])");
    std::cout << mem.response << std::endl;
    free(mem.response);
    return folders;
}

IMAP::memory IMAP::execute(const char *command) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
    struct memory chunk { (char *) malloc(1), 0 };
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    std::string finalURL;
    finalURL.append(this->url);
    finalURL.append("/");
    finalURL.append(this->mailbox);
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_ALL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, this->username);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, this->password);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, finalURL.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_function);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, command);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res != CURLE_OK) chunk.size = -1;
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    } else chunk.size = -1;
    if(chunk.size == -1) std::cerr << "ERROR >> Unable to call command: " << command << std::endl;
    return chunk;
}

size_t IMAP::write_function(void *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
    size_t real_size = size * nmemb;
    auto *mem = (struct memory *) userp;
    char *ptr = (char *) realloc(mem->response, mem->size + real_size + 1);
    if(ptr == NULL) return 0;
    mem->response = ptr;
    memcpy(&(mem->response[mem->size]), data, real_size);
    mem->size += real_size;
    mem->response[mem->size] = 0;
    return real_size;
}

void IMAP::select(const char *box) {
    this->mailbox = box;
}
```

**IMAP.h**

```
#ifndef MAILDUCK_IMAP_H
#define MAILDUCK_IMAP_H


#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <json/json.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>

enum {
    IMAP_DEFAULT_PORT = 993,
};

enum IMAP_CODE {
    IMAP_SUCCESS = 1,
    IMAP_FAILED = 0
};

class Folder : public std::vector<Folder> {
public:
    std::string name;
};

class IMAP {
private:
    const char *url, *username, *password, *mailbox = "";
    int port;
    struct memory { char *response; size_t size; };
    memory execute(const char *command = nullptr);
    static size_t write_function(void *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp);
public:
    IMAP(const char *url, int port);
    IMAP_CODE auth(const char* username, const char* password);
    std::vector<Folder> getFolders();
    void select(const char *mailbox);
};


#endif
```

I've been stuck on this for a bit, so I appreciate any insight anyone could provide.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! For all who get stuck like me:

Apparently the rest of the data is stuck in the header data, so add this:

```
struct memory chunk { (char *) malloc(1), 0 };
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, header_callback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, (void *)&chunk);
```

And then my write function is exactly like the other one...

```
size_t IMAP::header_callback(char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
    size_t real_size = size * nmemb;
    auto *mem = (struct memory *) userp;
    char *ptr = (char *) realloc(mem->response, mem->size + real_size + 1);
    if(ptr == NULL) return 0;
    mem->response = ptr;
    memcpy(&(mem->response[mem->size]), data, real_size);
    mem->size += real_size;
    mem->response[mem->size] = 0;
    return real_size;
}
```

Now I'm getting the full response.